# Facebook OAuth Unable to Connect

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, xamarin

I have been trying to create an iOS App using Xamarin (i.e. using Xamarin.iOS on C#) and I have run into an error I can't seem to resolve.

Basically, I have entered all the (correct) details into the default Facebook iOS SDK object as directed in the sample documents. However whenever I click login, the page returns 'unable to connect to server'.

The (URL Decoded) link the SDK sends me to is listed below:

```
https://m.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=(ID-REDACTED)&default_audience=friends&display=touch&e2e={"init":REDACTED }&redirect_uri=fb-ID-REDACTED://authorize/&response_type=token,signed_request&return_scopes=true&scope=&sdk=ios&sdk_version=4.2.0&state={"REDACTED":"REDACTED= ","0_auth_logger_id":"REDACTED","com.facebook.sdk_client_state":true,"3_method":1}
```

Pointing to this in a browser returns me to a blank page (when I enter in my ID which I have removed from the link above). I'm pretty certain this is due to an error in the way I have set up my application on Facebook as opposed to an error with the SDK (I'm using the default provided by Xamarin). I have removed the app from Sandbox Mode as directed and I have tried to follow the instructions provided on a couple of forum posts but nothing has changed and I am at a loss right now...

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I've managed to solve my issue...

For some really odd reason, m.facebook.com and facebook.com were added as entries in the hosts file (meaning that they were essentially blocked domains). This was weird given that I could access facebook from standard browsers like safari/firefox (just not the safari browser in the simulator).

If you have a similar issue, please change the hosts file (follow some tutorials online).